# Conversion of string to datetime fails with exception how to find which row causes it

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm currently importing some data from a very old database (access 2.0) into a sql server 2012 database. I imported all of the data (including the date field as it had values of 01.01.105 for 01.01.2005 ) into varchar fields.

Then I'm trying to import the data from the temporary table into the maintable. 
Until that point it all works as expected, but as soon as I started to import the data
into the maintable (from the temptable) I ran into an error with the datetime field in the maintable.

I always get an error message there.

**SQL**
    The fields in mytemptable are (Nr - int and datum - varchar(50)) the fields in mymaintable (orderNo - int and orderDate - Datetime).

```
INSERT INTO mymaintable (orderNo, orderDate) SELECT
    Nr,
    TRY_PARSE(CASE WHEN len(datum) = 9
        THEN left(Datum,6) + CAST((CAST(right(Datum, 3) AS int) + 1900) AS varchar(4)) + ' 00:00:00.000'
        ELSE datum  + ' 00:00:00.000'
    END AS DATETIME USING 'de-DE') AS datum
FROM mytemptable;
```

**Error message**

> Msg 6521, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 A .NET Framework error occurred
>   during statement execution:  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:
>   SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM. System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:     at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)    at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime value)    at
>   System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.CXVariantBase.DateTimeToSSDate(DateTime
>   dt)

**Additional infos**

I tried only the select part with the same result, but another set of data (only 1k out of the 20k rows) functions without raising the error.

Edit:
I tried to solve the problem with what was suggested in another post to use datetime2 instead of datetime and that functioned. BUT when I tried to find the rows that way by getting those where the datetime2 conversion returned null I received no result. Which means in essence DAtetime conversion fails, but datetime2 conversion does not fail at all.

**Question**

From what I saw (as I used it on a different part of the data already successfully) it seems not to be a general error, but one data related. 
So my question is there:

Is there any way of finding out which exactlyrow(s) is causing the problems?

*(as I understood try_parse it should return null when a conversion error happens and NOT throw an exception)*

Thanks

Comment: Quickly skimming through the code I think the problem arises from the else statement. Else `ELSE datum  + ' 00:00:00.000'`. Shouldn't this be NULL if the parsing failed. If datum is NOT 9 characters long the else statement will be executed. If the character length is very long wouldn't this create a date value that would be over the maximum 9999 year? That is where your overflow would be coming from

Comment: You should be able to find these for yourself. You know that the successfully convert to `datetime2`. You know that they don't convert to `datetime`. `datetime` has a more restrictive range of years that it works for, and those years are mentioned in the error message. So, having converted to `datetime2`, search for those where the year is < 1753.

Comment: ah tnx forgot to mention there. the datum is either 9 or 10 characters long (wil edit the post there). it is either MM.DD.YYY (with year representing 1990 + YYY = the real year) or it is 10 characters long with MM.DD.YYYY   I had added the time to the date as I had conversion errors when I didn't at first. 

But in total its only those two variants (doublechecked with len only those 2 date lengths are there)

Comment: @damien: tnx (only found out that datetime2 functioned after creating this question. the <1753 helped a lot there. will create an answer there accordingly.  tnx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As datetime2 functions but datetime fails one must take into account that datetime is more restrictive than datetime2 in regards to dates. Thus by modifying the SQL select it can be found out easily where the error occurs:

```
 SELECT
    Nr,
    datum
FROM mytemptable
WHERE datum is not null and 
    TRY_PARSE(CASE WHEN len(datum) = 9
        THEN left(Datum,6) + CAST((CAST(right(Datum, 3) AS int) + 1900) AS varchar(4)) + ' 00:00:00.000'
        ELSE datum  + ' 00:00:00.000'
    END AS DATETIME2 USING 'de-DE') < '01.01.1753 00:00:00.000';
```

The "datum is not null" part has been added to make sure only "unknown" problem zones are found.
If the above does not find any results, then the same should be made with the maximum date (instead of the minimum date) that datetime finds acceptable.

That way one can find out easily for which rows the conversion failed.